# Convert jdom2 Document to DOMSource

Tags: java, jdom, jdom-2

I have an XML as `jdom2 Document` delivered by an `URIResolver` and need to convert it to a `DOMSource`.

But I have no Clue how I could do that. I know that a `org.w3c.dom.Node` can be used to create a `DOMSource` but I also have no glue how to convert a `jdom2 Document` to a `org.w3c.dom.Node`.

Can anyone give me some tips or hints how to solve my Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little research I found this http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/DOMOutputter.html

and by using trhe DOMOutputter it is just:

```
org.jdom2.Document doc = //some jdom2 Document
org.w3c.dom.Document outputDom = new DOMOutputter().output(doc);
```